# universal properties of dependent types

Tags: category-theory, universal-property, homotopy-type-theory

What is the universal property of dependent product / dependent sum? (I want to see a diagrams)
They are must be different from usual ones, aren't they?

(i'm trying to understand category theory after I learned homotopy type theory. Is there a possibility to learn a category theory without learning some mathematical foundations like ZFC or HoTT?)

Comment: Well, first, you need to figure out how to encode dependent types. And then you'll be halfway to figuring out what dependent sums and products are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: [dependent sum](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dependent+sum), [dependent product](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dependent+product).  It's certainly not necessary to learn a foundation in order to learn category theory; there are now several good books on category theory out there, like Awodey's and Leinster's.